# Best way to track campaign transactions in Google Analytics

Tags: regex, google-analytics

We have just begun trying two price comparison websites that are using different source, medium and campaign values in Google Analytics.

I want to try to track sales from these to the product and notice that in Analytic Goals they are fine for setting up a goal that would end in our transaction confirmation url but need to have a funnel url that ends with, for example below

utm_source=pricerunner&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=pricerunner

Anybody have any idea how to do this using the end of a url? All I can see if GA is the entire url value or "begins wih"

I have tried using regex but nothing is being tracked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The campaign parameters needs to be passed in the url from the price comparison website to landing page (probably a product page at your end). At that point the GA session gets automatically associated with the utm parameters, and you do not track those url parameters subsequently in your funnel.

If you want to see the funnel for a specific pricce comparison website you can use a GA segment to isolate the goal traffic based on the campaign name. that should do the trick